# Error when using variable in SQL clause with arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management

Tags: arcpy, datetime, query-table

When I hard code a date my SQL query works fine

```
where_week = "dtrepor > ‘2017-04-21 07:00:00’"
```

but when I try to use a variable it booms out.
This variable prints to the exact same date and time but doesn’t work when substituted

```
my_OneWeekAgo = my_now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
SQLdateFrom = my_OneWeekAgo.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 07:00:00")
print SQLdateFrom

2017-04-21 07:00:00
```

This errors out

```
where_week = "dtrepor > 'SQLdateFrom'"
```

Here is the error

```
An underlying database error occurred. [C:\Users\mandrews\Documents\WeeklyIncidentMaps\WeeklyVehicleTheft.gdb\MyRecords]
Failed to execute (MakeQueryTable).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your variable into your string using [Python Formatting](https://pyformat.info/).

```
my_OneWeekAgo = my_now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
SQLdateFrom = my_OneWeekAgo.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 07:00:00")
print SQLdateFrom

where_week = "dtrepor > '{0}'".format(SQLdateFrom)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I figured that out just after I posted the question.  This is how I got it to work!    But your version look cleaner!   where_week = "dtrepor > '" + SQLdateFrom + "'"

Comment: This answer was very helpful and this website explains what passing a variable into a string is all about! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3